# Skyrim BlackSmith potion effects

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I drink 2 blacksmithing potions will it double the the effect? I have 2 potions that will improve my smithing by 20% for some time. If I drink them both, will it become 40%?

Answer (score 3):

Potions do **NOT** stack. So no, if you drink them both you won't reach 40% in smithing.

The only potions that stack are the restorative ones.

Answer (score -1):

Last I played Skyrim potions which were stacked in your inventory/have the same strength would not stack, so in your case no they will not.

However if you had two potions of different strengths, say 20% and 15% they would stack multiplicatively ie 1.20x1.15 = 1.38 so those two together would give you 38%. It is very likely that they patched this at some point though because you could make your own potions and have many different strengths of potions and then stack them all for very large bonuses.

Comment: Then you were using mods because this has *never* been the case.

Comment: No but I literally haven't played the game since release week so it's very possible that this has been patched for years.

Comment: I played the game on a console with no internet access. I know what was and wasn't on the game when it was released. You are wrong.

Comment: Well I played the PC version so maybe it was a bug only in the PC version? I am not wrong, I did it many times and that is the reason I stopped playing the game having 5000 one handed and one shotting dragons was boring.

Comment: In fact you could even do it to your equip able items if you used the increase effects potion then put on your enchanted armour the enchantment would be multiplied.